# Subsituting expressions for expressions

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, expression-construction

I'm trying to define functions using other functions, like so:

```
f[a_, b_] := a/b;
a[c_] := c;
b[d_] := d;
```

Now what I want to be able to do is two things:

1. Solving f[a_,b_] for c so that the output is c=f*d
2. Deriving f[a_,b_] directly for c so that the output is similar to this: D[f[a_,b_],c_]=1/d

As you can tell, my knowledge on defining functions properly is pretty shaky, I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this that I'm just not nearly experienced for to think of it.

Thanks  -A Mathematica beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've understand you. Something like this?:

```
With[{a = a[c], b = b[d]}, D[f[a, b], c]]
With[{a = a[c], b = b[d]}, Solve[f == f[a, b], c]]
```

> ```
> 1/d
> {{c -> d f}}
> ```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks! I circumvented using the "with" notation by defining f[a_,b_] as a[c]/b[d], is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: @F.E. I don't think there's any serious downside, it's just OK to use `a[c]` and `b[d]` directly. Of course it's better to use `With` when there's a lot of `a[c]`/`b[d]` to write.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

### Calculations about equality

There are different kinds of "equality" used in computer programming.  In Mathematica, `==`, or `Equal` is used to *assert* equality.  `1==1` is a `True` statement, and `1==2` is `False`.  `f == a/b` is a statement about the relationship between `f`, `a` and `b`.

You shouldn't use `:=` to assert equality between `f` and `a/b` or `c/d`.  Rather, make the assertion like this:

```
f == a[c]/b[d]
(*produces f == c/d *)

Solve[ f == a[c]/b[d], c]
(* {{ c -> d f }} *)
```

### Calculations using the functions

The syntax `:=` means `SetDelayed`, so when you say `f[a_, b_] := a/b` you are *instructing* Mathematica (as opposed to *asserting*) to replace `f[x,y]` with `x/y`.

Your second question could be rephrased as "how do I instruct Mathematica to call the functions f, a and b so that my derivative is calculated".  Answer: when you call `f[a[c], b[d]]` it will evaluate into `c/d` so that

```
D[f[a[c], b[d]], c]
(* produces 1/d *)
```